# Ao popular a lista, está vindo nula

Tags: c#

No meu App eu populo dois grids. Isso tá ok. Eu pego os dados de um serviço, desse modo:

```
dataGrid.ItemsSource = await dataService.GetLiberaAsync();
itensGrid.ItemsSource = await dataService.GetItensLibAsync(_idorcamento);
```

Isso está correto. Bem, acontece que preciso gerar um gráfico com algumas informações do grid de itens. Na página do gráfico tentei fazer algo parecido, mas não está dando certo e pelo visto não deveria mesmo. Na página do gráfico tentei fazer semelhante ao que vinha fazendo na outra página e não está dando certo, fiz assim:

```
List<ItensLib> item = new List<ItensLib>();
.......
private async void RetornaItens(double idorcamento)
{
    item = await dataService.GetItensLibAsync(idorcamento);
}
```

Como posso pegar os dados que vem do serviço. Preciso fazer um cálculo antes e depois gerar o gráfico. No aguardo.
Método que pega os dados no serviço.

```
public async Task<List<ItensLib>> GetItensLibAsync(double id)
        {
            try
            {
                string url = $"http://www.meu_site.com.br/autorizador/api/itens/{id}";
                var response = await client.GetStringAsync(url);
                var itenslib = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ItensLib>>(response);
                return itenslib.ToList();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Também criei uma property e nada também. Fiz assim:

```
private List<ItensLib> itens;
        public List<ItensLib> Itens
        {
            get
            {
                return itens;
            }
            set
            {
                if (value != null)
                    itens = value;
            }
        }
```

e tentei popular assim:

`Itens = await dataService.GetItensLibAsync(idorcamento);`

Comment: Como os dados estão vindo? Já tentou dar um cast? `await dataService.GetItensLibAsync(idorcamento).Cast<ItensLib>();`

Comment: @Francisco, não, nem sequer pensei nessa possibilidade. Vou tentar. O que fiz também, foi criar uma property e mesmo assim nada, mas vou na sua linha.

Comment: @Francisco, erro, dizendo que não tem uma definição para Cast. Veja a minha edição